# Combine results of two queries with the same value into one row

Tags: sql-server, database

Here is my query:

```
select fldUserId, count(*) AS TOTAL
from tblWorkHistory
where fldStatus = '1'
group by fldUserId
union
select fldEmpID, count(*) AS TOTAL
from tblQAHistory
where fldStatus = '1'
group by fldEmpID
```

Output:

```
fldUserId  TOTAL

16070004    34
19100015    1
19100015    7
191014571   3
```

I want to combine both rows with '19100015' into one row.

Comment: Do you understand the significant difference between UNION and UNION ALL? I suspect you want UNION ALL - though rare it is possible for the same ID and count to exist in both resultsets and your choice of UNION will remove them since they are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your query as a sub-query:

```
with cte as (
    select fldUserId, count(*) as TOTAL
    from tblWorkHistory
    where fldStatus = '1'
    group by fldUserId
    union
    select fldEmpID, count(*)
    from tblQAHistory
    where fldStatus = '1'
    group by fldEmpID
)
select fldUserId, sum(TOTAL) as TOTAL
from cte
group by fldUserId
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to group just once on the outside

```sql
select
  t.fldUserId,
  count(*) as TOTAL
from (
    select fldUserId
    from tblWorkHistory
    where fldStatus = '1'
    union all
    select fldEmpID
    from tblQAHistory
    where fldStatus = '1'
) t
group by
  t.fldUserId;
```